# React Native App - RN with Apple HealthKit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, healthkit

I want to build a Fitness App that can access health data from Apple HealthKit.
I believe i can use many packages like **"rn-apple-healthkit"**, **react-native-fitness**,
**react-native-health**.
Is there any way i can access Apple HealthKit using just the RN's Native Modules, NativeEventEmitters??

All the projects i found online use some or the other open-source package. 
Can i build my project with pure react native modules??

Calling out all the RN gurus.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the projects require an open source module is because React Native does not have the correct bindings to the Apple HealthKit.

Supporting this is not a priority of the core React Native team, so it becomes a community effort to support the bindings.

If none of the OSS modules work for you, I'd suggest building your own module. You can get started here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro

Answer (score 1):

Since the time this question was asked, there is a module available for accessing Health data on iOS with React Native.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-health